# XmlSerializer adding empty "<script/>" tag to output

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

On an ASP.NET MVC 3 (.NET 4.0) site which serves up XML documents using an `XmlSerializer` and serializing (relatively straightforward) objects via `Serialize()`, I've noticed that at some point in the last few weeks, it has started inserting an empty `<script/>` element as the first child of the root level object.

e.g. an object which used to serialize as..

```
<Information xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <MeetingInfo>
      <VenueName>PORT MACQUARIE (NSW)</VenueName>
      ...
```

Now serializes as..

```
<Information xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <script/>
   <MeetingInfo>
      <VenueName>PORT MACQUARIE (NSW)</VenueName>
      ...
```

The serialization is performed by a custom `ActionResult` thus:

```
public class XmlResult<T> : ActionResult
{
    public T Obj { get; set; }

    public XmlResult(T obj)
    {            
        this.Obj = obj;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(this.Obj.GetType());
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        xs.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.Output, this.Obj);
    }
}
```

There is no variable named `script` anywhere in the code base, certainly not in any of the objects being serialized.

I rolled my code back to where is was a month ago (when it was definitely **not** inserting the `<script/>` tags, and lo, that code is now inserting them.

Where could this have come from? Any Windows updates in the last month that affected the .NET framework that could have caused it? And why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question - just as there was no spoon in The Matrix, there was no `<script/>` tag.

View the response in Firefox - no `<script/>` tag.

View the response in IE - no `<script/>` tag.

But view the response in my usual browser, Chrome, and there's that `<script/>` tag.

View *Source* in Chrome (rather than just viewing the XML as content) - no `<script/>` tag.

So it's some weirdness in Chrome's displaying of XML content. Nothing to do with the serialization.

**Edit:** tracked it down. It's the [Ripple](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/installing_the_ripple_emulator.html) emulator installed as part of the Blackberry 10 WebWorks SDK. With that Chrome extension disabled, the mystery `<script/>` tag vanishes.

Comment: Thank you.  If you hadn't mentioned Ripple I would have still been scratching my head :)

Answer (score 0):

The XML Serializer is not producing a `script` tag when you have nothing in your object named `script`.

However, you are writing to `HttpContext.Current.Response.Output`, which may very well contain a `script` tag.

If your result output is meant to be *only* the XML, then can you do a "flush" first?